# What is difference between Pyarrow arguments for Pandas readers?

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

[Pandas' documentation explains how to use `PyArrow` as the backend for IO methods.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/pyarrow.html#i-o-reading)
However, I couldn't understand from it the difference between these two options:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(data, engine="pyarrow")
# and
df_pyarrow = pd.read_csv(data, dtype_backend="pyarrow")
```

What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `engine` specifies the CSV *Parser engine to use*. The available options are `c`, `python`, and [`pyarrow`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/csv.html#usage). Where as the `dtype_backend` argument is to let pandas know that we want Arrow backed types(Not the numpy types) by default.

I would suggest to read this [excellent article from Marc(Pandas Core Developer)](https://datapythonista.me/blog/pandas-20-and-the-arrow-revolution-part-i) that covers pandas 2.0 in detail.

> In the pandas 2.0 release candidates there was a `dtype_backend` option
> to let pandas know we want Arrow backed types by default. The option
> was confusing since not all operations support generating Arrow backed
> data yet, and it was removed. For I/O operators that support creating
> Arrow-backed data, there is a `dtype_backend` parameter:
>
> ```
> import pandas
>
> pandas.read_csv(fname, engine='pyarrow', dtype_backend='pyarrow')
> ```
>
> Note that the engine is somehow independent of the backend. We can use
> PyArrow function (`engine`) to read CSV files while using columns with a
> NumPy data type (`backend`), and the other way round.